# Excel pass/fail which only triggers the fail after 2 values don't meet the requirements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a pass/fail check that returns a fail only **after** 2 values in the range fail to pass the check. I've wrote the start of the check however it already returns the "Fail" straight after the first failing value.

For example: Pass/Fail check if all values are above 20.

```
20
20
20
---
good

20
19
20
---
still good

28
10
19
---
fail (since 2 values fail to meet the required value)
```

In my sheet 5 values need to be checked which need to be in a certain range defined in a other location (XX1 and XX2 in formula). The formula I used so far is:

```
=IFS(AND(E37:E41>=MIN(XX1);E37:E41<=MAX(XX2));"Pass";TRUE;"Fail")
```

Comment: `MAX(XX2)` and `MIN(XX1)` are just equivalent to `XX2` and `XX1` btw.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(E37:E41,"<"&XX1)+COUNTIFS(E37:E41,">"&XX2)>1,"Fail","Pass")`

Comment: If(count(A1:C1,20)>=2,"Pass","Fail")

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(E37:E41,">="&XX1,E37:E41,"<="&XX2)>3,"Pass","Fail")`

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(E37:E41,">="&XX1,E37:E41,"<="&XX2)>COUNTA(E37:E41)-2,"Pass","Fail")`

Comment: Thanks for the help @BigBen the fail now triggers on 2 values which is awesome. However I'm also checking if the average value of the 5 is still within range of the values defined in XX1 and XX2 and that check broke now.

Comment: `=AND(AVERAGE(E37:E41)>=XX1,AVERAGE(E37:E41)<=XX2)`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow now, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: That is the formula to check the if the average of `E37:E41` is between XX1 and XX2.

Comment: I probably formulated it wrong, I need to check the average as well as the range stated in the original post. Am I correct when I say that that is not possible?

Comment: If you want to combine the checks together, try: `=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(E37:E41,">="&XX1,E37:E41,"<="&XX2)>COUNTA(E37:E41)-2,AVERAGE(E37:E41)>=XX1,AVERAGE(E37:E41)<=XX2),"Pass","Fail")`.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, please share in `Answer` you have invested lot of time on this query, i want to vote up for your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options:

Using `COUNTIFS` and `COUNTA`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(E37:E41,">="&XX1,E37:E41,"<="&XX2)>COUNTA(E37:E41)-2,"Pass","Fail")`
```

If you need to also check that the average falls between `XX1` and `XX2`, then use `AND` and `AVERAGE` along with the formula above.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(E37:E41,">="&XX1,E37:E41,"<="&XX2)>COUNTA(E37:E41)-2,AVERAGE(E37:E41)>=XX1,AVERAGE(E37:E41)<=XX2),"Pass","Fail")`
```

Answer (score 0):

### 3 Conditions `IF` Statement

1. `AVERAGE(E37:E41)>=XX1`
2. `AVERAGE(E37:E41)<=XX2`
3. `COUNTIF(E37:E41,"<20")<2` i.e. not more than 1 value is lt 20 (or at least 4 values are gte 20).

```
=IF(AND(AVERAGE(E37:E41)>=XX1,AVERAGE(E37:E41)<=XX2,COUNTIF(E37:E41,"<20")<2),"Pass","Fail")
```